# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Authentication not working after deploying the app - Nginx with mutliple apps

Tags: authentication, nginx, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm trying deploy my application to our internal server with Nginx. It's an ASP.NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages site.  I was asked to include some authentication for logging purposes. Eventually everything was working fine on my computer. I used this site to add cookie based authentication:
https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/335/simple-authentication-in-razor-pages-without-a-database

I did some modifications to handle a few more users within the `OnPost()` method. Though I don't think that would be the problem.

It might be important to mention this is not the only .net core app running on the server. The setup is similar to this:

app1: our.domain.com

app2: our.domain.com/app2 (this is the one I have problems with)

everything works properly except the login. When I try to log in, if the password and username is correct it gets redirected to the proper page, however it seems like there is no identity or it cannot find it afterwards.

On my first attempt, I found the following error in the kestrel service log:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery[7]
```

I could make that disappear with using `services.AddDataProtection()`, however the problem is still the same, I get redirected - or get the error message if the login attempt is incorrect - but still can't access the authorised folder and e.g. the `HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName)?.Value` returns null or empty.

I did a quick test and added the same login page and an authorised folder, and the other dependencies to the other app. And there it works. I didn't even included `services.AddDataProtection()` in the startup.cs. The login works perfectly. Though it's using .net core 2.1.

So it might have to do something with the rooting? Or I don't know. I'm totally lost. I'm not a full time developer, more like a hobbyist and I'm completely stuck at this moment. Maybe I messed up something within the startup.cs? Or I should add something else? Or is it something with the cookies handling? I did make a lot of searching, no luck so far.

Here is the relevant part of my startup.cs:

```
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
                .AddDbContext<Models.UserAccessDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("appConnection")))
                .BuildServiceProvider();


            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            // https://hanselman.com/blog/DealingWithApplicationBaseURLsAndRazorLinkGenerationWhileHostingASPNETWebAppsBehindReverseProxies.aspx
            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All;
                options.AllowedHosts = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AllowedHosts")?.Split(';').ToList<string>();
            });


            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(cookieOptions =>
            {
                cookieOptions.LoginPath = "/";
            });

            services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/admin");
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);


            services.AddDataProtection()
                .SetApplicationName("app")
                .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"/var/dpkeys/"));


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {


            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();

                app.Use((context, next) =>
                {
                    context.Request.PathBase = new PathString("/app");
                    return next.Invoke();
                });
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();


            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Update:
One small detail. The cookie is created and I can see it within the Chrome's inspector. But the site/app doesn't see me as an authenticated user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I had problems with the cookie settings. One more difference between the two pages, that one if it uses `font-awesome`, which means I have some external cookies on my site. As a wild guess, first I set

```
options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax;
```

since the other cookies had that mode.

And just like that it started to work on the hosting server as well! Now the app recognises the cookie created after the log in.